# MySQL: How to get the LAST 10 rows instead of the FIRST 10 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the command

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 10
```

to retrieve the firs 10 rows of the table.

Is there a way to do the same thing but with the last 10 rows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: without an `ORDER BY`, your current query isn't necessarily returning the "first 10 rows of the table"

Comment: A query such as you have provided does not necessarily get the first ten rows of a table; it get the first tens rows of the query results. Without a precise enough ORDER BY, LIMIT is not deterministic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your query gets 10 arbitrary rows, which are generally the first 10 rows inserted into the table.  But, you should not depend on this ad-hoc functionality.

If you have an auto-incremented id, then you get the first ten rows by doing:

```
select t.*
from t
order by id
limit 10;
```

To get the last ten rows, use `order by id desc`.